# iText - Output file font looks blurry after using PdfCleanUpProcessor

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I'm using iText 5.5.8 to remove some text in a rectangle in my PDF, exactly following [this example](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/content-extraction-and-redaction/removing-content#1030-removecontentinrectangle.java). E.g. the code snippet like below:

```
final Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 12, 300, 21);
final PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(inputPDF);
final PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(outputPDF));
for (int i=1;i<=reader.getNumberOfPages();i++) {        
    cleanUpLocations.add(new PdfCleanUpLocation(i, rect, BaseColor.WHITE));
}

PdfCleanUpProcessor cleaner = new PdfCleanUpProcessor(cleanUpLocations, stamper);   
cleaner.cleanUp();

stamper.close();
reader.close();
```

However, in the output file, all those bold texts weight becomes heavier, and looks blurry. Meanwhile, all normal texts are still same as original.

[image: See this image for illustration]

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Comment: You need to provide source code.

Comment: ... and the sample file, too.

Comment: Added code and output sample

Comment: by sample file I meant a PDF so one can see what's inside.

Comment: (Actually I assume the **bold** text actually is a *poor man's bold* generated by using *stroke-and-fill* instead of *fill* for text rendering, and for some reason the line width has changed in the course of cleanup. But to verify and fix something like that, one needs to reproduce the issue...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I have resolved this problem by **downgrading the iText** back to version 5.5.4!

Comment: Have you tried *upgrading* to 5.5.9?

Comment: And if it really is a regression, you sort of have the moral responsibility to provide a file that reproduces the issue, so it can be verified with 5.5.9 and if necessary, fixed in 5.5.10.

Comment: Yes, 5.5.9 has the same issue as 5.5.8.

And since the original PDF file contains sensitive personal information thus I can't upload it here.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another possible solution for your problem which worked for me: [iText 5.5.11 - bold text looks blurry after using PdfCleanUpProcessor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44304695/itext-5-5-11-bold-text-looks-blurry-after-using-pdfcleanupprocessor)

In version 5.5.10 this worked for me:
I downloaded the jar file with the sources (itextpdf-5.5.10-sources.jar), imported it into a new eclipse project, edited the .java file (comment out the two lines of code), compiled it, replaced the original .class file with the newly compiled .class file and created a jar file with the same name.
Hope this helps anyone with the same problem!

Comment: Please describe full solution in your answer, do not just post links.

Comment: I'll simply mark this question a duplicate of the referenced one.