# Using PdfCleanUpTool or PdfAutoSweep causes some text to change to bold, line weights increase and double points change to hearts

Tags: java, pdf, itext7

I have weird problem when I try to use iText 7. Some parts of the PDF are modified (text to change to bold, line weights increase and double points change to hearts). In iText version 5.4.4 this didn't happened, but every version since that I have tried cause this same problem (5 or 7).

Does anyone have a clued why this is happening and is there anything I could to do to bypass this problem? Any help would be appreciated!

If more information is needed, I will try to provide it.

[image: Original]

[image: Modified]

Below is simple code that I used to test iText 7.
[Example PDF Files](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1hldcKYopupZivQzD7Wdbx7GN5P2eLDOo?usp=sharin)

```
package javaapplication1;

import com.itextpdf.kernel.colors.ColorConstants;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.geom.Rectangle;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfReader;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfWriter;
import com.itextpdf.pdfcleanup.PdfCleanUpLocation;
import com.itextpdf.pdfcleanup.PdfCleanUpTool;
import com.itextpdf.pdfcleanup.autosweep.ICleanupStrategy;
import com.itextpdf.pdfcleanup.autosweep.PdfAutoSweep;
import com.itextpdf.pdfcleanup.autosweep.RegexBasedCleanupStrategy;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;


public class JavaApplication1 {
    
    public static final String DEST = "D:/TEMP/TEMP/PDF/result/orientation_result.pdf";
    public static final String DEST2 = "D:/TEMP/TEMP/PDF/result/orientation_result2.pdf";
    public static final String DEST3 = "D:/TEMP/TEMP/PDF/result/orientation_result3.pdf";
    public static final String SRC = "D:/TEMP/TEMP/PDF/TEST_PDF.pdf";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File file = new File(DEST);
        file.getParentFile().mkdirs();

        new JavaApplication1().manipulatePdf(DEST);
        new JavaApplication1().manipulatePdf2(DEST2);
        
        
        try (PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(SRC), new PdfWriter(DEST3))) {
            final ICleanupStrategy cleanupStrategy = new RegexBasedCleanupStrategy(Pattern.compile("2019", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE)).setRedactionColor(ColorConstants.PINK);
            final PdfAutoSweep autoSweep = new PdfAutoSweep(cleanupStrategy);
            autoSweep.cleanUp(pdf);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        }
     
    }

    protected void manipulatePdf(String dest) throws IOException {
        PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(SRC), new PdfWriter(dest));

        List<PdfCleanUpLocation> cleanUpLocations = new ArrayList<PdfCleanUpLocation>();

        // The arguments of the PdfCleanUpLocation constructor: the number of page to be cleaned up,
        // a Rectangle defining the area on the page we want to clean up,
        // a color which will be used while filling the cleaned area.
        PdfCleanUpLocation location = new PdfCleanUpLocation(1, new Rectangle(97, 405, 383, 40),
                ColorConstants.GRAY);
        cleanUpLocations.add(location);

        PdfCleanUpTool cleaner = new PdfCleanUpTool(pdfDoc, cleanUpLocations);
        cleaner.cleanUp();

        pdfDoc.close();
    }
    
    protected void manipulatePdf2(String dest) throws IOException {
        PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(SRC), new PdfWriter(dest));

        // If the second argument is true, then regions to be erased are extracted from the redact annotations
        // contained inside the given document. If the second argument is false (that's default behavior),
        // then use PdfCleanUpTool.addCleanupLocation(PdfCleanUpLocation)
        // method to set regions to be erased from the document.
        PdfCleanUpTool cleaner = new PdfCleanUpTool(pdfDoc, true);
        cleaner.cleanUp();

        pdfDoc.close();
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Which iText 7 version exactly do you use? I cannot reproduce the issue, I don't get to see such effects. But they do remind of effects of [the iText 5 bug identified here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44308968/1729265), probably iText 7 cleanup had a similar bug which meanwhile has been fixed.

Comment: I tested using current snapshots, iText 7.1.14-SNAPSHOT and cleanup 2.0.6-SNAPSHOT.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I was initially testing with version 7.1.8 (but I'm quite sure that also tested with version 7.1.12) and Sweep 2.0.5. Now, have been busy with other things that I did not notice the new versions (thanks for pointing that out @mkl). I did quick test with 7.1.13 version and it seemed to fix the issue. I also tried same versions that you and didn't notice any difference then to only changing to 7.1.13. I will do some more testing with different PDFs to verify it this fixed everything. Try to post final results soon. But thanks once more already @mkl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for late response. I managed now verify that updating to latest versions corrected this problem. Thanks to @mkl pointing this out.

Problem solved